# Backup PostgreSQL database using java throwing db doesnot exist error

Tags: java, postgresql

I am able to successfully backup and restore through cmd using this

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5433 --username postgres --no-password -f C:\tmp\test.sql mydb
```

But when I am trying to run the same thing through Java, I get this output:

```
            String[] cmdDump = {
            "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_dump.exe",
            "--host", "localhost",
            "--port", "5432",
            "--username", "test",
            "--no-password",
            "--verbose",
            "--file", "C:\\tmp\\test.sql",
            "mydb"
    };
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p;
    p = rt.exec(cmdDump);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader bufErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    String ll;
    p.waitFor();
    int processComplete = p.exitValue();

    if (processComplete == 0) 
    {
        while ((ll = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ll);
        } 
        System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
    } 
    else 
    {
        while ((ll = bufErr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ll);
        } 
        System.out.println("Could not create the backup");

    }
```

Output:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydb" failed: FATAL:  database "mydb" does not exist
Could not create the backup
```

Not sure why a database that is accessible from cmd is not visible from Eclipse.
My `pgpass.conf` file is configured correctly for my login user.

Comment: There's a mismatch in what you typed, not sure if intended or a typo. Command line has `-p 5433`, while code has `"--port", "5432",`.

Comment: also different usernames between command and java: test vs postgres.

Comment: typo in port. My wrong. When corrected, the process is getting hung in p.waitFor();